# What is the difference between: "aquel" and "aquél"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, acentuación, ortografía

I see both "aquel" and "aquél" used in similar context and was wondering if there is any difference in meaning of those two words.

Answer (score 23):

**Aquel** is an adjective whereas **Aquél** is a pronoun.

> Aquel edificio es grande. -*That building is large.*
>
> Aquél es grande. -*That one is large.*

Comment: thanks, so I understand that the same would apply to 
aquella, aquellos, aquellas vs aquélla, aquéllos, aquéllas?

Comment: @kristof yes, and *este, éste, esta, ésta, esa, ésa* etc... etc...

Comment: from RAE: "En este último caso escr. con acento cuando existe riesgo de anfibología." So the accent is not compulsory unless the term can be ambiguous (and it usually is not ambiguous). So "Aquel" can also be a pronoun. http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=aqu%C3%A9l

Answer (score 20):

Until 2010, the official rule was to use accent (*tilde diacrítica* in Spanish) to differentiate the pronoun from the adjective, as @snumpy has already said.

The (IMHO) sad news is that since 2010 the rules have been changed by RAE, and now it is recommended to avoid the use of the accent in this case, even when there is an obvious case of ambiguity:

[Eliminación de la tilde diacrítica en el adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos incluso en casos de posible ambigüedad](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#novOrto5)

---

#### Some examples:

1. Sólo / Solo:

   > *Estaré **sólo** dos meses* (I'll stay **only** two months).
   >   *Estaré **solo** dos meses* (I'll be **alone** during two months).
2. Éste / Este:

   > ***Éste** sólo gustó a los más exigentes* (**This one** was only liked by the most demanding).
   >   ***Este** solo gustó a los más exigentes* (**This** solo [Music] was liked by the most. demanding)

   - In the first line, may be written with comma to avoid ambiguity: *Éste***,** sólo gustó a los más exigentes.
3. Aquéllos / Aquellos:

   > *¿Por qué compraron **aquéllos** libros usados?*  (Why did **they** buy used books?)
   >   *¿Por qué compraron **aquellos** libros usados?*  (Why did they buy **those** used books?)

   - In the first line, the subject may be enclosed with commas due to the "*hipérbaton*": *¿Por qué compraron, **aquéllos**, libros usados?*

Comment: A lot of people ignore the RAE, though, especially outside Spain.

Comment: @KefSchecter: after these new rules, me too...

Comment: I preffer continue use that rules. I dont understand why the RAE eliminate its

Comment: I still prefer it how it was before the elimination the letter *ç* and the spelling *muger*. And of course there are others who prefer it before the case system was eliminated.

Comment: The link to the new RAE recommendation is broken. Could you fix it please?