# ¿Cuándo se debe acentuar el pronombre "este"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, ortografía, acentuación, pronombres-demostrativos

Hace pocos días, en Meta de Stack Overflow en Español, [alguien comentó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/945/83) que no debería corregir a alguien si yo cometo fallos en mi redacción. El [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28985/jfreechart-into-jsplitpanel-using-netbeans#comment46696_28985) del que hablo:

> Bienvenida a SOesp. **Éste** es el sitio Stack Overflow en español. Has de editar tu pregunta y dejarla en español o será cerrada. También has de especificar más: poner algo de codigo que tengas, cosas que has intentado/descartado, ... etc

En los comentarios de mi [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/947/83) dicen que "Éste es el sitio" no debería llevar tilde porque no es un pronombre (yo creo que lo es).

Me gustaría saber: **¿qué hay mal en mi frase?, ¿qué puedo mejorar?** Y respecto a los demostrativos/pronombres, **¿cuál es la normativa actual respecto a estas palabras?**

Comment: ¡Hola lois6b y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Yo también hago alguna _batida_ de vez en cuando añadiendo tildes en [es.so], suelen faltar muchas :) De todos modos, no me queda demasiado claro cuál es tu pregunta concreta en todo esto. ¿Podrías editar tu publicación para clarificarlo, usando también un título más descriptivo? Ah, _este es el sitio_ para mí es la forma correcta, sin tilde; [_éste_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GoCiPnl|GoDU5PI) (con tilde) se usa en ciertos casos cuando hay riesgo de ambigüedad.

Comment: @fedorqui, mis preguntas las acabo de poner en negrita.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Ten en cuenta que en este sitio hay mucha gente que ama el idioma español y le gusta verlo bien escrito, por no hablar de los que tenemos [TOC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trastorno_obsesivo-compulsivo) (me incluyo) y sentimos la imperiosa e irresistible necesidad de poner las tildes que faltan. :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, sisi, y lo aprecio (yo soy tiquismiquis). Por eso pregunto que más cosas están mal, para aprender.

Comment: Parece que Carlos y fedorqui se me han adelantado ;) Precisamente iba a hacerte notar la tilde en "código", pero déjame decirte que el argumento de "no corrijas si tú también tienes fallos" es el típico que usan las personas que se molestan por que les corrijan, es una estupidez como una casa(si las personas que tienen fallos no pudieran corregir, absolutamente nadie podría corregir), y como cualquier otra falacia no vale para nada positivo, solo sirve demostrar que no se tiene otro argumento. Ni caso.

Comment: @nox es cierto que todos cometemos fallos, pero a la hora de corregir (aunque no corregía su ortografía si no su elección de lenguaje) se ha de tener más cuidado al escribir. Y fue lo que hice, escribir con cabeza haha pero no la suficiente para algunos hehe

Comment: @Nox anímate a contestar, pues hemos encontrado artículos que se contradicen un poco. Lo mismo tú puedes decantar la balanza :D

Comment: Pregunta similar: [What is the difference between: “aquel” and “aquél”](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31/12637)

Comment: De hecho, la *Nueva gramática* ya no lo considera pronombre: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/40868/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no debe llevar tilde. Lo recomendado por la RAE es escribir:

> Este es el sitio Stack Overflow en español.

Y no:

> <s>Éste</s> es el sitio Stack Overflow en español.

Hasta hace no demasiado tiempo, existía la regla por la que se ponía una tilde con función de desambiguación. Sin embargo, la RAE indica:

> [**El adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos, sin tilde**](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde)
>
> La palabra *solo*, tanto cuando es adverbio y equivale a solamente (*Solo llevaba un par de monedas en el bolsillo*) como cuando es adjetivo (*No me gusta estar solo*), así como los demostrativos este, ese y aquel, con sus femeninos y plurales, funcionen como pronombres (*Este es tonto; Quiero aquella*) o como determinantes (*aquellos tipos, la chica esa*), no deben llevar tilde según las reglas generales de acentuación, bien por tratarse de palabras bisílabas llanas terminadas en vocal o en -s, bien, en el caso de aquel, por ser aguda y acabar en consonante distinta de n o s.

Véase la cita a la función histórica (sigo citando la página antes enlazada):

> Aun así, las reglas ortográficas anteriores prescribían el uso de tilde diacrítica en el adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos para distinguirlos, respectivamente, del adjetivo solo y de los determinantes demostrativos, cuando en un mismo enunciado eran posibles ambas interpretaciones y podían producirse casos de ambigüedad
>
> (...) Por eso, **a partir de ahora se podrá prescindir de la tilde en estas formas incluso en casos de ambigüedad. La recomendación general es, pues, la de no tildar nunca estas palabras.**

Nótese que es una recomendación, no una regla.

Recomiendo la lectura completa del artículo, pues rompe con la forma de pensar de los que estudiamos la lengua hace unos cuantos años (no muchos, que soy joven :D).

Tal y como apuntamos en los comentarios y Carlos Alejo en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18540/1674), la RAE aún mantiene referencias al uso de la tilde para resolver ambigüedades. Por ejemplo, en la entrada de *este* leemos:

> [este<sub>2</sub>, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GoCiPnl%7CGoDU5PI)
> Del lat. iste, -a, -ud 'ese2'.
> En aceps. 6-10 las formas este y esta, y sus plurales respectivos, **pueden escribirse con acento (éste, ésta, etc.) cuando existe riesgo de ambigüedad**.

Donde las acepciones de la 6 a la 10 son las correspondientes a los pronombres demostrativos.

Sin embargo, no deberíamos tenerlo en cuenta, tal y como explica [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/4182/guifa) en los comentarios:

> Tened en cuenta que la nueva Ortografía que suprimió terminantemente las tildes en los demostrativos salió en 2010, frente al DPD que salió en 2005. Por eso, en caso de conflicto entre las dos obras, debemos seguir la Ortografía.

Lecturas complementarias al respecto:

- [El adverbio “solo” y los pronombres demostrativos sin tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17599/1674)
- Artículo completo de la Ortografía de la lengua española [*3.4.3.3 La tilde diacrítica en el adverbio* solo *y en los pronombres demostrativos*](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fuDhAkNQKJLicUVg), muy parecido a la entrada descrita antes (*El adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos, sin tilde*).

---

Volviendo al caso que nos ocupa, *este* tampoco en el pasado habría necesitado del uso de tilde, pues no hay ambigüedad alguna: te estás refiriendo a *Stack Overflow en español* y no hay ningún otro nombre al que puedas estar refiriéndote al usar *este*.

Sobre el texto completo, me suena algo forzado. ¿Lo tradujiste de la versión inglesa? Yo diría algo así como...

> Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, donde la pregunta debe utilizar este idioma. De lo contrario, será cerrada. También deberías adjuntar el código que tengas, así como todo aquello que hayas intentado/descartado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y el artículo, me dispongo a leerlo. Y yo que me comía la cabeza pensando en el caso de "solo" y "sólo" ... hahah

Comment: En mi respuesta he citado el DPD, que dice que se puede tildar en casos de ambigüedad. Según tu respuesta, ¿el DPD está obsoleto?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo lo que veo es una contradicción entre los dos artículos.

Comment: @fedorqui, no, no lo traduje. Fue como me salió en ese momento ^^'

Comment: Vale, creo que no hay tal contradicción, tu artículo dice que sí puede haber casos de ambigüedad, tal y como indica el DPD, pero son raros y rebuscados, por lo que en la práctica se debe escribir sin tilde y resolver las ambigüedades de otra forma.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo la entrada de [este/éste](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GoCiPnl|GoDU5PI) en el DRAE también menciona _En aceps. 6-10 las formas este y esta, y sus plurales respectivos, pueden escribirse con acento (éste, ésta, etc.) cuando existe riesgo de ambigüedad_. Supongo que lo mantienen de forma transitoria, pues es una cambio grande (y traumático para muchos).

Comment: A mí me parece más una recomendación que una regla. La frase en negrita da a entender esto mismo: "...a partir de ahora se podrá prescindir de la tilde en estas formas incluso en casos de ambigüedad" ; no es una frase muy categórica precisamente, no está expresada como una ley. Además, teniendo en cuenta que en el artículo referenciado por Carlos se recomienda directamente evitar los casos de ambigüedad, creo que la intención es precisamente esa, que se eviten los casos de ambigüedad eligiendo otra forma de expresión, así la necesidad original de la susodicha tilde desaparece y deja de usarse.

Comment: Sigo un pelín perdido. Significa que no se debe poner tilde, aún en caso de ambigüedad, pero se puede?

Comment: @lois6b significa que está muy desaconsejado. En el caso concreto de tu pregunta no hay ambigüedad posible, por lo que yo creo que roza lo incorrecto. Para los hipotéticos casos de ambigüedad, se recomienda no usarlo cambiando la estructura de la frase.

Comment: @fedorqui, bueno, tilde fuera pues. Parece que la RAE quiere que no escribamos tan mal, quitanto aquello que pueda generar duda hahah "que no saben cuando poner tilde? que no la pongan " XD

Comment: @lois6b tantos años machacándonos con las tildes y al final se deciden por no usarlas :) Por cierto, para reír por internet en castellano [¡se usa _ja ja ja_!](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17219/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui :O me van a decir como reírme?  * cry in spanish *

Comment: Tened en cuenta que la nueva Ortografía que suprimió terminantemente las tildes en los demostrativos salió en 2010, frente al DPD que salió en 2005.  Por eso, en caso de conflicto entre las dos obras, debemos seguir la Ortografía.

Answer (score 2):

Ciertamente hay que ponerse un poco tiquismiquis para responder a tu pregunta, aunque creo que es importante dejar clara la postura de la RAE al respecto de las [tildes en pronombres](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ#321):

> Los demostrativos este, ese y aquel, con sus femeninos y plurales, pueden ser pronombres [...]. Sea cual sea la función que desempeñen, los demostrativos siempre son tónicos y pertenecen, por su forma, al grupo de palabras que deben escribirse sin tilde según las reglas de acentuación [...]. Por lo tanto, solo cuando en una oración exista riesgo de ambigüedad porque el demostrativo pueda interpretarse en una u otra de las funciones antes señaladas, el demostrativo llevará obligatoriamente tilde en su uso pronominal. Así, en una oración como la del ejemplo siguiente, únicamente la presencia o ausencia de la tilde en el demostrativo permite interpretar correctamente el enunciado: *¿Por qué compraron aquéllos libros usados?* (*aquéllos* es el sujeto de la oración); *¿Por qué compraron aquellos libros usados?* (el sujeto de esta oración no está expreso, y *aquellos* acompaña al sustantivo libros).

Así pues, en tu caso no parece haber lugar a duda, luego debería haberse escrito sin tilde. Sin embargo, tal y como dice el artículo enlazado por fedorqui en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18539/12637), "los casos reales en los que se produce una ambigüedad que el contexto comunicativo no es capaz de despejar son raros y rebuscados, y siempre pueden evitarse por otros medios", así que en la práctica puedes escribirlo siempre sin tilde directamente.

Por otro lado:

- Pusiste *código* sin tilde.
- Es redundante poner puntos suspensivos junto a un *etc*. O uno u otro, pero no ambos. Si pones puntos suspensivos deben ir pegados al último sustantivo, sin necesidad de coma: *poner algo de codigo que tengas, cosas que has intentado/descartado...* Si pones *etc* debe llevar punto al ser una abreviatura: *poner algo de codigo que tengas, cosas que has intentado/descartado, etc.*

Comment: Sí, lo de "código" me di cuenta (demasiado tarde y no pude editarlo). Gracias por responder a *¿qué hay mal en mi frase?*
@carlosalejo Consideras que mi comentario es un ejemplo de mal uso del lenguaje y por tanto no puedo "corregir" a la usuaria?

Comment: @lois6b creo que en este caso estoy de acuerdo con Nox en su comentario. Errar es humano, y tener faltas de ortografía no debería invalidar tu argumento, lo único que pasa es que el corrector puede acabar siendo corregido a su vez. Pero eso no quiere decir que tu corrección no tuviera razón en un principio. Seguro que una afirmación así se podría considerar una [falacia *ad hominem*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumento_ad_hominem): se desacredita al orador por sus faltas de ortografía para invalidar el argumento, más que invalidar el argumento en sí.

Comment: además cuando ni estaba corrigiendo su escritura, solo su elección de idioma (¿Viste? aprendí xD puse "solo" sin tilde hhehe)

Comment: En principio, la *Nueva gramática* ya no los considera pronombres: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/40868/.

Answer (score -2):

Se usa cuando ya te referiste en algún momento a algo/alguien.

Por ejemplo:

Stack Overflow es un lugar para hacer preguntas, éste es de mucha utilidad.

(Si estoy mal espero me corrijan).

Comment: Precisamente es este el uso que la RAE ya no recomienda. Mira lo comentado en las otras respuestas. Además, la pregunta no es esta, sino si es necesario usar tilde o no.