# ¿Cómo se destaca una palabra de un texto que ya está en cursiva?

Tags: ortografía, escritura

Estaba revisando [una respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18539/1674) cuando quise mencionar un artículo de la RAE.

El título de ese escrito es:

> 3.4.3.3 La tilde diacrítica en el adverbio *solo* y en los pronombres demostrativos

Con *solo* en cursiva.

Sin embargo, al ir a referenciarlo quise poner cursiva en todo el título, por lo que *solo* dejaba de aparecer destacada.

¿Indica la RAE algún criterio para destacar una palabra cuando ya está en cursiva todo el texto que lo rodea? Se me ocurren comillas (simples o dobles), pero más por criterio estético que por conocimiento técnico.

Comment: Lo mismo me ha pasado a mí a veces. Por lo general, la RAE (o la Fundéu muchas veces, cuando habla de extranjerismos) piden que una palabra se escriba en cursiva o entre comillas, entendiendo que esto último sirve cuando no se dispone de la cursiva. Por tanto, generalizando, entiendo que la forma de destacar dentro de un texto ya en cursiva consiste en, como dices, usar comillas.

Comment: Creo que es tan sencillo como usar cursiva en todo el texto menos en la palabra a resaltar. Lo he visto así bastantes veces. El caso es que resalte. :-)

Comment: @Gorpik ah, entiendo. ¿Y precisa si deben ser comillas simples o dobles?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo pues yo nunca lo había visto pero me parece muy ocurrente :)

Comment: @fedorqui Supongo que dobles, las comillas simples creo que no se consideran un signo español. De todos modos, la contestación de Carlos Alejo es la correcta en este caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He encontrado esto en la Ortografía 2010 ([epígrafe 3.4.8.2.2](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fGXBbgYJWWwdjBCU)):

> Se llaman *usos metalingüísticos* aquellos en los que un término, una expresión o un enunciado se emplean no para comunicar el mensaje que contienen, sino para decir algo de ellos [...]. En los textos impresos, en lugar de emplear comillas, se marcan los usos metalingüísticos en cursiva (si el texto base está en redonda) o en redonda (si el texto base está en cursiva).

También en el [epígrafe 3.4.8.2.3](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UGXBDpSPhKIOakNS):

> Los títulos de libros, revistas y periódicos, por el contrario, se citan en cursiva (si el texto base va en redonda) o en redonda (si el texto base va en cursiva).

Más adelante, en [el mismo epígrafe](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KuoJjNRHSLVjkPWC):

> Suelen escribirse entre comillas los apodos y alias que se intercalan entre el nombre de pila y el apellido [...]. También puede optarse, en este caso, por escribir el apodo en cursiva (o en redonda, si el texto base está en cursiva).

Y por fin, el [epígrafe 2.1.1](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QeHkRtkrDkKiFQWI):

> Las voces extranjeras deben escribirse en los textos españoles con una marca gráfica que destaque su condición de palabras pertenecientes a otra lengua: preferentemente en cursiva en la escritura tipográfica (siempre que el texto base esté escrito en redonda; pero en redonda, si el texto base está escrito en cursiva) [...].

Tu caso sería el primero, el de citar *solo* con un uso metalingüístico para expresar algo sobre el término. Pero como ves, esa forma de proceder es generalizada.