# ¿Cómo se escriben los pódcast y programas de noticias de televisión?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

¿Cursivas o comillas? Si se quiere mencionar el nombre de un pódcast, ¿este debe tener mayúsculas en todas las palabras relevantes? ¿Debe estar escrito en cursiva o entre comillas? Tengo la misma duda con respecto a los programas de noticias de televisión.

> Ejemplo 1: El otro día escuche el pódcast «Diarios para Emprendedores»
> y me gustó mucho.
>
> Ejemplo 2: El otro día vi una noticia en el programa «Antena 3
> Noticias» que me pareció interesante.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En [¿Cómo se destaca una palabra de un texto que ya está en cursiva?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18585/1674) se preguntaba algo un poco diferente, pero se encuentra la respuesta: _Los títulos de libros, revistas y periódicos, por el contrario, se citan en cursiva (si el texto base va en redonda) o en redonda (si el texto base va en cursiva)._ Seguro que hay por allí alguna pregunta similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundéu tiene un [documento detallado](https://www.fundeu.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CursivasGuiaFundeu.pdf) sobre el uso de las cursivas. Al final de la página 8, el documento dice

> Los títulos en las portadas que identifican obras como libros, discos o revistas, así como los que llevan cuadros, películas, series de televisión, etc., se escriben en cursiva, con independencia de la lengua:
>
> - Se proyectan los dos filmes que hicieron al alimón: *Un perro andaluz* y *La edad de oro*.
> - Ni *Las meninas* ni el resto de las obras propiedad del Estado están aseguradas.
> - La portada del semanario *Der Spiegel* mostraba a un jubilado con gorra.
> - La película *Minority Report* está basada en un relato titulado *El informe de la minoría*.

En los ejemplos que pone Fundéu se puede ver también la regla sobre las mayúsculas, que está recogida en el [artículo sobre las mayúsculas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas) del DPD, punto 4.17:

> [Se escriben con mayúscula:]
> 4.17. La primera palabra del título de cualquier obra de creación (libros, películas, cuadros, esculturas, piezas musicales, programas de radio o televisión, etc.); el resto de las palabras que lo componen, salvo que se trate de nombres propios, deben escribirse con minúscula: *Últimas tardes con Teresa*, *La vida es sueño* [...] En el caso de los títulos abreviados con que se conocen comúnmente determinados textos literarios, el artículo que los acompaña debe escribirse con minúscula: *el Quijote*, *el Lazarillo*, *la Celestina*.

En resumen, los títulos de obras se escriben **en cursiva, y la primera palabra del título con mayúscula**. Nótese que, en el caso de títulos de obras extranjeras, Fundéu prefiere utilizar la ortografía del idioma correspondiente: [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) en inglés (*Minority Report*) o mayúsculas en todos los sustantivos en alemán (*Der Spiegel*).