# Uso de ésto en español

Tags: pronombres, ortografía, acentuación

Cordial saludo,

Estaba escribiendo un resumen para una materia de la universidad y me entró una duda. La expresión que la generó fue:

"Un monitor en java no permite comunicación con programas en C, a menos que se use una herramienta para **ésto**"

Mi duda es **ésto** en este caso lleva tilde? He estado leyendo y encontré que la RAE desestima su uso desde el 2010, pero me gustaría saber de todas formas si con la antigua norma se debería tildar esa palabra en ese caso.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cuándo se debe acentuar el pronombre “este”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/cu%c3%a1ndo-se-debe-acentuar-el-pronombre-este)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Esto* no lleva tilde nunca. Las antiguas reglas permitían la tilde diacrítica para los pronombres demostrativos, pero *esto* siempre es pronombre (no como *esta* y *este*, que pueden ser pronombres o bien determinantes). Por tanto, no hay una ambigüedad que se pueda resolver con una tilde diacrítica. Por lo demás, es una palabra llana terminada en vocal, con lo que según las reglas generales tampoco le correspondería llevar tilde.

"Una herramienta para este" no llevaría obligatoriamente tilde (ni siquiera antes de la reforma de 2010): desde las normas de 1952 ([fuente](http://revistas.rae.es/brae/article/view/159/408)) la tilde ya era optativa salvo que hubiera ambigüedad. Ejemplos en los que hay ambigüedad (del enlace anterior, a mí no se me ocurrían):

> Dijo que ésta mañana vendrá.
>
> Dijo que esta mañana vendrá.

Comment: En caso de que usara "...una herramienta para éste", tendría tilde?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para contestar al comentario.