# "Aquel vestido es bonito, pero yo prefiero este": ¿por qué "este" ya no se considera pronombre?

Tags: gramática, categorías-gramaticales, pronombres-demostrativos

Entre los años 2009 y 2011 se publicó la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* en sus diferentes versiones. Como podéis ver en este [artículo](https://www.redalyc.org/journal/921/92153510005/html/), una de las novedades que incluía es que se pasaba a considerar que los únicos pronombres demostrativos de la lengua española son los neutros "esto", "eso" y "aquello". En una frase como, por ejemplo,

> Aquel vestido es bonito, pero yo prefiero este

"este" ya no se considera un pronombre, sino un determinante de un sustantivo elidido.

Nunca he entendido la razón de este cambio de criterio. Un cambio análogo se ha hecho en la [gramática del catalán](https://giec.iec.cat/textgramatica/codi/16.4.1), aunque mis colegas de trabajo aseguran que todavía no se ha introducido en las pruebas de acceso a la universidad de lengua catalana, pero no tengo constancia de que se haya hecho un cambio análogo en otras lenguas románicas (puede que sí, pero lo desconozco). En italiano estoy casi segura de que no se ha hecho.

¿Alguien me lo sabría explicar?

Comment: Y en rigor todos los pronombres no son más que "seudo-adjetivos" de sustantivos elididos.

Comment: @Rodrigo: No me parece que eso sea así.

Comment: Claro, tienes toda la razón con mostrarte dudosa con esa decisión. Mi comentario era para decir que si aceptamos tal explicación, habría que eliminar de cuajo la categoría de los pronombres. Todos los pronombres se justifican por la existencia de algún sustantivo elidido.

Comment: Y lo único que diferencia _éste_ de otros pronombres (como _mío_) es que es homónimo del adjetivo correspondiente. ¿Por qué no funciona la nueva regla con una oración equivalente?: "Tu vestido es hermoso, pero yo prefiero el mío""

Comment: @Rodrigo:  Si lees el artículo que he enlazado, verás que con los posesivos pasa una cosa similar: ya no se consideran pronombres.

Answer (score 1):

El artículo al que aludes, "*¿Determinante o pronombre? Las claves transversales en la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española de la RAE*", fue escrito por Antonio Delgado Torrico de la Escuela Europea I, Bélgica y si creo estar en lo cierto es también profesor en el Instituto Cervantes de Fez, en el Aulario de Mequínez, (Marruecos).

Aunque en general desarrolla y explica consideraciones históricas, morfológicas y de sintaxis de la "Nueva gramática" de la Real Academia Española, creo  entender que hay algo erróneo o al menos una interpretación un tanto confusa en la documentación, no en sí por tu parte, sino por la falta de aclaración suficiente de Antonio para disipar dudas, pues algunos párrafos no son todo lo elocuentes que deberían ser, ya que mezcla pensamientos o teorías que no son las que al final se han llevado a cabo, aunque el artículo sea del 2016. " *En la Nueva gramática básica de 2011, de carácter puramente divulgativo, se decanta claramente por la primera opción: se piensa hoy generalmente que todos los demostrativos, excepto los neutros, son determinantes*".

"*¿Determinante o pronombre? Las claves **transversales***...". El problema se encuentra en este mismo eslogan, pues realmente es el tema que nos ocupa "**"este" como pronombre**", aunque no da, ni habla centralmente de que son esas claves (clases) transversales, pues son el núcleo de la cuestión, más se limita a realizar una crítica de lo que esto supone dentro de la "Nueva Gramática" y de la complejidad de la cuestión.

Después de una introducción histórica, el número 2 del artículo, trata de las **Clases Transversales** donde hace una enumeración, empero, olvida explicar suficientemente que significa ser una "**Clase Transversal**" y esto es lo que verdaderamente confunde.

Así, en ese mismo epígrafe 2.1.1, después de la "tabla 1", cuando pone el ejemplo de la bicicleta, "*No quiero cualquier bicicleta, quiero **esa***", más abajo en otro párrafo, dice, "*Sin embargo, el análisis de* **esa como pronombre** *en la frase anterior también es considerado válido en la Nueva gramática de 2009*", difumando cualquier explicación más profunda de esta "Transversalidad" y que nos hace pensar que si "**esa**" es pronombre, entonces encamina la duda hacia la posibilidad de que "**este**", también pueda ejercer la función como pronombre.

---

En el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, habla de los demostrativos cuando dice...

3.2.1. Demostrativos. Los demostrativos **este, ese y aquel**, con sus femeninos y plurales, **pueden ser pronombres** (cuando ejercen funciones propias del sustantivo): Eligió este; Ese ganará; Quiero dos de aquellas; o adjetivos (cuando modifican al sustantivo).... Las formas neutras de los demostrativos, es decir, las palabras esto, eso y aquello, que **solo pueden funcionar como pronombres**...

---

Es decir, "**esto, eso y aquello...**", se consideran formas neutras y solo pueden funcionar como pronombres, la razón que se exhibe es que actualmente en español no existen sustantivos considerados neutros por la RAE.

---

En la Nueva gramática básica de la Real Academia Española y Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española en su apartado 8, dedicado a los determinantes y pronombres, si podemos comenzar a entender ese sentido de transversalidad del que adolecíamos.

8

**Determinantes y pronombres**

8.1 Clases y subclases de palabras

.....

**Algunas de estas clases muestran propiedades de varias categorías, por lo que se consideran clases transversales. Así, los demostrativos pueden ser determinantes (este avión, esa fábrica), adjetivos (el individuo ese), pronombres (Esto no es harina) y adverbios (Viven aquí).**

......

*Así leyendo este párrafo se advierte que "este", se encuentra dentro de esas palabras consideradas como clases transversales y por tanto si puede ejercer como función de pronombre*.

8.3.5.1 Elipsis, referencia y pronombres. La elipsis es el silencio en la expresión de una secuencia que está latente en el mensaje. En el segundo miembro de la oración compuesta María va al cine, pero yo no iré, se suprime por consabido el grupo al cine. En la interpretación del mensaje, el que descodifica restituye los segmentos elididos.

88
Tras los determinantes es muy frecuente la elipsis del sustantivo:

en esta casa y en aquella Ø [casa]

mis padres y los Ø tuyos    [padres]

unos árboles frondosos y otros Ø secos  [árboles]

tres días de trabajo y tres Ø de descanso   [días]

La tradición gramatical analizaba estos determinantes como pronombres. **Tal opción alterna en la actualidad** con el análisis que postula un elemento elidido en aquellos contextos en los que, aunque no manifiestos en la expresión, se hallan presentes y son necesarios para la interpretación del mensaje.

**Los dos análisis posibles son**, en consecuencia, los siguientes:

- *en esta casa y en aquella* [**aquella como pronombre**]
- *en esta casa y en aquella Ø* [**aquella como determinante**].

No hay elipsis en el caso de las unidades neutras, ya que en español no existen los sustantivos neutros. Se consideran, pues, solo pronombres las formas esto, ello, etc.

Por tanto en el caso que nos ocupa, "**este**", la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española expresa que de hecho las dos opciones pueden tratarse en la actualidad, ya que estas clases y subclases de palabras pertenecen a las llamadas, "clases transversales" al mostrar propiedades que se encuentran integradas en varias categorías, de esta manera puede continuar considerándose que "este" realiza una función como pronombre o por el contrarío como determinante de un sustantivo elidido. En consecuencia y de tal suerte que "**este**", como pronombre, aún existe y podemos continuar aplicándolo.

---

Notas

---

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

3.2. Otros casos de tilde diacrítica

3.2.1. Demostrativos.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/tilde#321

---

Real Academia Española
Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española
Nueva gramática básica de la lengua española

https://enclave.rae.es/gramatica/html/NG_BASICA_MASTER2AULA.html

---

Nueva gramática de la lengua española

Sala_prensa_Dosier_Gramatica_2009.pdf (11. EL GÉNERO)

https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Sala_prensa_Dosier_Gramatica_2009.pdf